# Wildfly 9 session expired but no authentication unless browser closed

Tags: session, authentication, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have set up a custom `security-domain` in Wildfly 9.0.2.Final for testing which looks like this:

```
<security-domain name="LDAPAuth" cache-type="default">
<authentication>
  <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
    <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial"
                   value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url"
                   value="ldap://localhost:389"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
    <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=People,dc=acme,dc=com"/>
    <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
    <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=Roles,dc=acme,dc=com"/>
    <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
    <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
    <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL_SCOPE"/>
  </login-module>
</authentication>
</security-domain>
```

In my web.xml I have referenced this `security-domain` name (LDAPAuth) in my `login-config`.

When I provide valid username and password configured in my local LDAP, I am allowed in, otherwise authentication fails.  This works great.  The problem is, once I've authenticated once, I'm never prompted again unless I close that browser window and open a new one.  It doesn't matter if I manually call `session.invalidate();` in my code, if the session just naturally expires (I have it set to 1 minute for testing), or even if I restart the server!  I'm new to Wildfly but my experience working with other apps servers tells me that I should be re-prompted in any of the above scenarios, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have **`BASIC`** authentication method configured in your `web.xml`. It means your browser keeps (remembers) the authentication data and sends them when application server ask for them. So it doesn't ask again the user. Use **FORM** authentication to avoid this behavior.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the best way to "logout" a user in JavaEE6 and newer is to call [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.logout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout()) rather than `session.invalidate();`